# How to back transform glm coefficients in order to plot results?

Tags: r, plot, glm, coefficients

So I have a glm with two predictor variables, and one response, and I need to back transform the estimates so that when I add them to my plot they are on the same scale as my data. I have been told to make an object of the predicted values as shown:

```
b0 <- #estiamte for intercept
b1 <- #estimate for first coeefficient
b2 <- #estimate for second coefficient

predicted.values <- b0 + data$firstpredictor * b1 + data$secondpredictor * b2
```

The trouble I am having is that my second predictor is a factor variable and therefore I get an error code since it is meaningless to multiply a factor.

Comment: If you fit default `glm` and `secondpredictor` is a factor, I think `b2` can't be single number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with `iris` data.

I missed a two level factor, that this case may give you only one coefficient for `secondpredictor`.

I'll use model `fit <- glm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)` and `Species` is factor with three levels.

```
fit

Call:  glm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)        Sepal.Width  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
           2.2514             0.8036             1.4587             1.9468  

Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  146 Residual
Null Deviance:      102.2 
Residual Deviance: 28   AIC: 183.9
```

As you can see in this model, `b0` is `2.2514`, `b1` is `0.8036` and `b2` is `1.4587` or `1.9468` depends on `Species`.

Let's take a look at first sample of `iris`, `iris[1,]`

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

And also, it's predicted value(`predict(fit, iris[1,])`) is `5.063856`.

Note that `Species` is `setosa` which is baseline of this categorical variable.

Then, predicted values can be calculated manually by `2.2513932 + 3.5*0.8035609 + 0` or `fit$coefficients[1] + 3.5 * fit$coefficients[2]`.

Then, to handle case with other factor, you can achieve it by

```
fit$coefficients[1] + iris$Sepal.Width * fit$coefficients[2] + fit$coefficients[3]  * (iris$Species == "versicolor") + fit$coefficients[4] * (iris$Species == "virginica")
```

You can check this result with

```
predicted.iris - predict(fit, iris)
```

or

```
var(predicted.iris - predict(fit, iris))
```